# Mensagem relacionada ao chat nos comentários em inglês

Tags: bug, status-futuro, tradução, comentários, chat

Quando há muitos comentários em uma pergunta/resposta o StackOverflow sugere que continuemos a conversa pelo chat.

Com isso, percebi que diversas palavras e frases ainda não foram traduzidas para o Português/Brasil:

[image: Screenshoot with the incorrect phrase - comments - chat]

E, é claro, o próprio chat também não foi:

[image: Chat screen - opened by br.stackoverflow.com link]

Comment: Conteúdo relevante: http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/10/sobre-partes-do-site-em-ingles

Comment: @bigown eu fiz a tradução e postei aqui justamente após ler tudo neste post.

Answer (score 5):

There are a few different requests grouped together here:

- `let us continue...` and the other *site* strings have been sent to the translator and will be imported shortly
- the *chat* itself is not being localized for now.

---

Há dois problemas agrupados aqui:

- `let us continue...` e outros textos do *site* já foram enviados ao tradutor e serão importados em breve
- o *chat* em si não será localizado por enquanto.

Comment: Hmm.... for me, is 2 requests about same thing : chat in portuguese. Anyway, thanks Skliwz :)

Answer (score 2):

Eu sugiro as seguintes traduções:

**Se alguém tiver uma tradução melhor, favor editar minha resposta**

## Frase no comentário

**English:** let us continue this discussion in chat – Patrick Maciel 16 mins atrás 
**Portuguese Brazil:** vamos continuar essa conversa pelo bate-papo – Patrick Maciel 16 minutos atrás

## Chat (página)

**load older messages:** Mostrar mensagens anteriores 
**Hint (title/alt in link) (load a few more earlier chat messages):** Carrega algumas mensagens enviadas há um momento atrás

**load to my last message:** Mostrar minha última mensagem 
**Hint (title/alt in link) (load all chat messages up to the last time I talked in this room): ** Carrega todas as últimas mensagens enviadas nessa sala

**full transcript:** Transcrição completa 
**Hint (title/alt in link) (view the complete archived chat history for this room):** Visualizar um histórico completo da conversa arquivada dessa sala

**highlights:** Realçar 
**Hint (title/alt in link) (Only show starred messages, and messages to the current user):** Mostrar apenas mensagens marcadas como favoritas

**all rooms:** todas as salas

**site rooms:** salas do site 
**Hint (title/alt in link) (all Stack Overflow em Português rooms):** Todas as salas do StackOverflow em Português-BR

**Discussion between Patrick Maciel and tiaguinhow:** Conversa entre Patrick e tiaguinhow

**Imported from a comment discussion on br.stackoverflow.com/questions/2086/…:** Referente aos comentários da seguinte conversa: br.stackoverflow.com/questions/2086/…

**leave (all):** sair (sair de todas) 
**Hint (title/alt in link) (leave this room):** Sair dessa sala
**Hint (title/alt in link) (leave all rooms):** Sair de todas as salas

**room▼:** Sala 
**Hint (title/alt in link) (more options for this room):** Mais opções para essa sala

**info:** Informação 
**Hint (title/alt in link) (about this room):** Sobre essa sala

**There are other rooms, with 116 users currently talking in 48 rooms.** Há outras salas, com 116 usuários conversando em 48 salas.

**enable desktop notification:** habilitar notificações na área de trabalho